# Cplex giving wrong result

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming, scip

I created a sample `test.lp` file as follows:

```
Maximize
    y

Subject To
 +x1+100M+3M2+x4-y+A=0
 x1-M-M2-10x4>=-20
 x1 - 3 M + M2 <= 100
 M - 3.5 x4 + M2= 0
 A+x1<=140
 
Bounds
 x1<= 40
 2 <= x4 <= 3
 0<=x1
Binary
 M
Integer
 A
End
```

Used all default settings, and the following commands: `read test.lp`->`opt`->`d sol v -`

Result is:

```
Variable Name           Solution Value
y                           172.500000
x1                           40.000000
M                             1.000000
M2                            9.500000
x4                            3.000000
A                             1.000000
```

However, the result should be `y=271.5` and `A=100`, the value of other variables seems okay.

This is also tested with *google OR-Tools* (*SCIP* solver), which gives proper results.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
Integer
 A
End
```

into

```
Generals
 A
End
```

you ll get the right solution

Comment: Ohh, General indicates integer. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer` (or `Integers`, or `Int`, or `Ints`) is a keyword in LP file that's been deprecated since a very long time (probably after CPLEX V4.0, in 1995). It was kept in the code only for compatibility with old LP files, and will not be used by CPLEX when writing an LP file.

It used to work as follows. If the bound of the variable was specified, then the variable is a general integer.  If the bound was not specified, then the variable is binary.

In your case, as `A` doesn't appear in the `Bounds` section, it is considered a binary variable. And indeed the value it has in the solution computed by CPLEX is coherent with this.

Using `display problem all` in the CPLEX Interactive will show the whole problem as it's known to CPLEX.  In your case, this ends with

```
[...]
Bounds
 0 <= x1 <= 40
 0 <= M <= 1
 2 <= x4 <= 3
 0 <= A <= 1
 All other variables are >= 0.
Binaries
 M  A
```

You can see how CPLEX considers `A` to be a binary variable.

Comment: Thanks, for the detailed explanation. `d problem all` really helped in testing.